# Use Loop to create Models for all combinations of order

Tags: r, loops, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to use a loop to create models for all combinations of p = 15 to 1, d=2 to 0, q = 15 to 1, then use a rolling forecast to evaluate those models, and pick out the one that say has the lowest mape (Accuracy(fc$mean,test)[,5]).

I'm not that good with loops, so any tips are greatly appreciated.  I have a working "before code" example below, and "after code" showing how I would like to modify it.

Before Code:

```
library("fpp")

h <- 5
tsTrain <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
tsTest <- window(hsales,start=1990)
n <- length(tsTest) - h + 1
ModFit <- Arima(tsTrain, order=c(15,2,15)
fc <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
for(i in 1:n)
{  
  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  reModFit <- Arima(x, model=ModFit)
  fc[i] <- forecast(reModFit, h=h)$mean[h]
}
```

After Code:

```
library("fpp")

h <- 5
tsTrain <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)
tsTest <- window(hsales,start=1990)
n <- length(tsTest) - h + 1

##Create models for all combinations of p 15 to 0, d 2 to 0, q 15 to 0

ModFit1 <- Arima(tsTrain, order=c(15,2,15)
ModFit2 <- Arima(tsTrain, order=c(9,2,15)
ModFit3 <- Arima(tsTrain, order=c(8,2,15)
.
.
.
ModFit15 <- Arima(tsTrain, order=c(0,2,15)
fc1 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
fc2 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
fc3 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
.
.
.
fc15 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1990+(h-1)/12, freq=12)
for(i in 1:n)
{  
  x <- window(hsales, end=1989.99 + (i-1)/12)
  reModFit1 <- Arima(x, model=ModFit1)
  reModFit2 <- Arima(x, model=ModFit2)
  reModFit3 <- Arima(x, model=ModFit3)
  .
  .
  .
  reModFit15 <- Arima(x, model=ModFit15)
  fc1[i] <- forecast(reModFit1, h=h)$mean[h]
  fc2[i] <- forecast(reModFit2, h=h)$mean[h]
  fc3[i] <- forecast(reModFit3, h=h)$mean[h]
  .
  .
  .
  fc15[i] <- forecast(reModFit15, h=h)$mean[h]
}

##Calculating mape for forecasts

Accuracy(fc1$mean,tsTest)[,5]
Accuracy(fc2$mean,tsTest)[,5]
Accuracy(fc3$mean,tsTest)[,5]
.
.
.
Accuracy(fc15$mean,tsTest)[,5]

##Return the order of the Arima model that has the lowest mape
ModFit5 ARIMA(10,2,15)  ##This is just an example, I don't know if this really the one with the lowest mape.
```

Update:

```
pvar<-1:15
dvar<-1:2
qvar<-1:15

OrderGrid<-expand.grid(pvar,dvar,qvar)


ModFit <-function(a,b,c,dat){
          m=Arima(tsTrain, order=c(a,b,c))
          return(m)
                            } 


Fits<-apply(OrderGrid,1,ModFit)
```

Error:

Error in Arima(tsTrain, order = c(a, b, c)) : 
  argument "c" is missing, with no default

Update:

```
ModFit <- function(x, dat){
m=Arima(dat, order=c(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]),method="ML")
return(m)
} 

Fits <- plyr::alply(OrderGrid, 1, ModFit, dat = tsTrain)
```

Comment: `expand.grid` can make you a matrix where each row corresponds to a unique set of parameters. Then use `apply` (or alply) to feed each row to Arima.

Comment: @RichardTelford Thank you, expand.grid is very handy!  I'm finding it a little tricky to combine apply with Arima to pass each row from the matrix I made with expand grid.  Do you have a tip on that part or do you know an example of something similar? I've added updated code from my attempt, along with the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `expand.grid` and `alply` as `apply` will simplify to a matrix of arima objects which will be a pain

```
pvar<-1:15
dvar<-1:2
qvar<-1:15

OrderGrid<-expand.grid(pvar,dvar,qvar)

ModFit <- function(x, dat){
          m=Arima(dat, order=c(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]))
          return(m)
} 

Fits <- plyr::alply(OrderGrid, 1, ModFit, dat = tsTrain)
```

`Fits` will be a list.

Comment: thank you for the code example.  When I try running your code I'm getting the following error.  Do you know what the issue is?   Error: Error in order[2] + seasonal$order[2] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Thank you, adding [[ got rid of the old error, and then I got a new one from the Arima part.  I was able to fix the new error by adding method="ML".  I've added the updated working code above.